# How to hide and show Android Soft keyboard from an Accessibility Service

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, accessibilityservice

I want to know how to hide and (after certain action) then show the Android Soft keyboard. This is fairly easy with API Level 24, however I am targeting API level 23.

Following is my code which works for API Level 24:

```
// to hide
getSoftKeyboardController().setShowMode(SHOW_MODE_HIDDEN);

// to show
getSoftKeyboardController().setShowMode(SHOW_MODE_AUTO);
```

How do I do same with API Level 23?

Answer (score -3):

Hide keyboard

```java
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I am within an accessibility service, so `this.getCurrentFocus` is not available

Comment: What do I pass for `view`? I do not have any `View` since its within an accessibility service.

Comment: this answer is not right and wouldn't work. Please delete it.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).