# Android Soft Keyboard is not working properly with Accessibility Service and WindowManager

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-windowmanager, accessibilityservice

So, finally here I'm,  after searching the **Google** and **SO** for this perticular problem which made me crasy from past 3 days. A lot of answers are out there but it seems that neither of them seems to solve this specific issue. Here is what I have found so far,

[Show keyboard automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759253/show-keyboard-automatically)

[Android soft keyboard not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266679/android-soft-keyboard-not-working)

[How to hide and show Android Soft keyboard from an Accessibility Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654606/how-to-hide-and-show-android-soft-keyboard-from-an-accessibility-service)

[Window manager blocking keyboard for apps underneath floating chat head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931143/window-manager-blocking-keyboard-for-apps-underneath-floating-chat-head)

[Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext)

[Android - Keyboard not appearing in floating window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572486/android-keyboard-not-appearing-in-floating-window)

---

## What I want to acheive

- I want to open a screen with `EditText` in it from `AccessibilityService` (This part is done).
- Open keyboard and type text in the `EditText`.
- Take the input text from `EditText` (with a button click), and send it to the `EditText` of **Messaging App**, and then perform a click event on **send** button in **Messaging App**. This all will be done using `AccessibilityService` and not by the user.
- The overlayed screen should be removed when user expand the `notification_panel` or press the `Back`, `Home` or `Recents` button from the navigation area.

---

## The Problem

**Im unable to handle keyboard and its input on an `EditText` inflated using `WindowManager` in an `AccessibilityService`.**

## Scenarios/use cases

[image: 2 images of different use cases]

### Scenario 1 (Image 1)

-> Inflated the view with window type `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` and window flag `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`.

***Able to acheive***

- I can listen to all events in `AccessibilityService`.
- I can remove the overlayed window when `notification_panel` expands.
- I can listen to navigation buttons, and handle the code accrodingly.

***Unable to acheive***

- Unable to show keyboard by clicking on `EditText` or programatically.

***what I have tried so far***

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        chattingLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
    } else {
        chattingLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
    }
```

and this (but not working)

```
val imm: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(someEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

---

### Scenario 2 (Image 2)

-> Inflated the view with window type `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` and window flag `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODEL`.

***Able to acheive***

- Show keyboard and type text.

**Unable to acheive**

- Can not trigger **events** in the `SccessibilityService`.
- Unable to trigger the `notification_panel` changes to remove overlayed window.
- Unable to trigger **navigation buttons (back, home, recents)** actions to remove overlayed window.

***What i have tried so far***

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        chattingLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
    } else {
        chattingLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
    }
```

---

`AccessibilityService` Config.xml file

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

I hope the problem is clear, please forgive for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of when you overlay screen the input manager required to meets the opacity condition not exceed InputManager.getMaximumObscuringOpacityForTouch() which is currently  0.8f.

Just set
**chattingLayoutParams.alpha = 0.8f** to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, the flags I went for are

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`

but you might need FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL if its a modal